# URL rewriting in php by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Please help to convert dynamic url to static url by htaccess in php.

Example 1:

`www.example.com/say.php?name=ksrtc-palakkad-kerala&id=c669239`      (Dynamic URL)

`www.example.com/say/ksrtc-palakkad-kerala-c669239.html`             (Static URL)

---

Example 2:

`www.example.com/index.php?name=ksrtc-palakkad-kerala&id=c669239`      (Dynamic URL)

`www.example.com/say/ksrtc-palakkad-kerala-c669239.html`             (Static URL)

Regards,
Prabhat

Answer (score 3):

You should create an .htaccess that looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Now the full path would be redirected to index.php - this will be your single entry point, you could access it through `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if I recall well.

Now it will be your job to write set of rules to know all the possible routes that this url matches (regular expressions), then parse the url and set the GET variables accordingly (from your second example - name, id). If the url doesn't match any of the known urls - forward it to your error page.

And also you should do reverse-routing, if someone opens an url with plain get variables like "index.php?name=ksrtc-palakkad-kerala&id=c669239" you should redirect with 301 PERMANENT REDIRECT to the "SEO" url "/say/ksrtc-palakkad-kerala-c669239.html"

If this doesn't answer your question, please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for reply I know I have to do with htaccess but I don't know how I should write rewriterule in htaccess for same  so that it will accept url "/say/ksrtc-palakkad-kerala-c669239.html